# Inset shadows declarations not working on latest Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css

Chrome version: 25.0.1364.172

The code:

```
<div style="
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 8px -10px red, inset 0px -5px 8px -10px red;
">
</div>
```

Can anyone give it a try ?

With this code, I was expecting to have inset shadows on TOP and BOTTOM only.

No dice.

http://jsfiddle.net/ngZNv/

If it does not work on your side either, can you please suggest a perhaps alternative way of doing this ?

This declaration seems to (more or less) work:

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px red, inset 0px -1px 0px red;
```

But it's a clearly different interpretation.

To sum it all up:
This works for Mozilla (without the prefix):

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 8px -10px red, inset 0px -5px 8px -10px red;
```

No luck on chrome.

Please advice

Comment: Make a jsFiddle so we can check! :)

Comment: I hate cowards that down vote without providing a reason for that.

Comment: Apologies. The downvote was mine. I thought the tooltip of the downvote was explanatory enough: *"This question does not show any research effort"*. It helps if you tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to solve the problem, and if you're specific about what goes wrong, what you expected and why, and if possible perhaps even quote from documentation why/how you expected your example to work.

Comment: Good Jeroen, so next time you do make a downvote, why don't you start to FIRST explain it and THEN downvote if you still don't agree? I really believe that's the right way of doing things.

Comment: Just a heads up MEM, this CSS (when changed to the -moz- prefix) also didn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Your attitude is pretty poisonous. Calling me a coward for asking for a fiddle, assuming i downvoted.

Comment: @CaptainCarl I haven't neither assuming you have downvoted me or calling you coward. As you may well see on my comment, I haven't mention you with a @. And thanks for your comment. I have added a fiddle once I see your comment. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the -10px is stopping the shadow from being displayed, that value is changing the spread of the shadow, so, it being negative doesn't make much sense. Not sure what you're intending it to look like. But it's at least visible if you change them to `10px` rather than `-10px`.

```
<div style="
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 8px 10px red, inset 0px -5px 8px 10px red;
">
</div>
```

The usage is as follows:

`box-shadow: [inset] <horizontal-offset> <vertical-offset> [blur] [spread] [color];`

EDIT:

Does this have a similar effect to what you want?

`-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px -5px #F00, inset 0px -5px 10px -5px #F00;`

Comment: The point was to play with the spread in order to make shadows on top and bottom only. If you checked on other browsers, it will to the trick.

Comment: Let me have a play and I'll come up with something :)

Comment: Have a try with the CSS I've put in my answer if you want.

Comment: `-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 10px -15px #F00, inset 0px -16px 10px -15px #F00;` How's that? I don't see any on the sides on mine :S, http://jsfiddle.net/ngZNv/2/